# Linking users to chrome flags page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-midi

I've created a site that utilizes the new Web Midi Api, native in Chrome Canary. 
Since web midi isn't enabled by default, I would like to simply direct my users to chrome://flags/#enable-web-midi where they can enable midi.

I discovered that using an anchor tag isn't allowed, nor is window.open("chrome://flags"). I'm wondering if there is a Chrome expert out there who could steer me in the right direction.
I want to make this enabling step as easy as possible for my users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://flags#enable-web-midi"});
```

This does not require any permission. (This assumes you are developing a [Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps), if you are making a normal site, then I don't think it's possible.)

Details on [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tabs#method-create).

Comment: Ah, thank you for the details yes.  This answers my question.